# What is fileencoding of .vimrc?

Tags: vimrc, encoding

I've upgraded vim and now it's unhappy about some UTF-8 values in my `.vimrc`.

This lead me to the question -- when vim reads `.vimrc`, what encoding does it assume the file has? I.e. what's `fileencoding` then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is whatever you define with `:scriptencoding`. It should be the first line in you `.vimrc` file, e.g.:

```
scriptencoding utf-8

set number
set ...
```

However, as per the Help for `:scriptencoding`, if you set the 'encoding' option in your vimrc, `:scriptencoding` must be placed after that.

Be aware that some options (`listchars` for example) only accept single width values.

Edit: Yeah, Vim is weird. `encoding` is for the editor itself, `fileencoding` is for the buffer and `scriptencoding` is for Vim scripts.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I was able to fix my installation with hacks. I'd appreciate if the answer was updated with an example of `~/,vimrc` showing how to use `scriptencoding`

Comment: @DimaTisnek done! I din't want to write it in the answer because it is not what you asked for but Vim's defaults are messed up IMHO and I think that's a good reason to try out Neovim (in fact I had to look in my old configuration to remember the syntax of `scriptencoding`)

Comment: @Tae, unless you on windows, where Neovim is still way behind vim.

Answer (score 1):

As hinted at in the help files (`:help scriptencoding`), if you do not use `scriptencoding`, vim does no conversion, effectively assuming the script is in the encoding of the `'encoding'` option.  This is very often `utf-8`, occasionally `latin1`.  Other encodings are possible.  Generally you want to use

```
scriptencoding utf-8
```

when your script file contains non-ascii characters and is encoding in utf-8.  If you use only 7-bit ascii characters, it is unnecessary.

`'fileencoding'` applies to the current buffer, not scripts.  When opening a file, vim tries to guess the encoding from the option `'fileencodings'`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I was able to fix my installation with hacks. I'd appreciate if the answer was updated with an example of `~/,vimrc` showing how to use `scriptencoding`